# an array of classes draws to much memory

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Im working on project that displays a grid of images to the screen. i then realized that i will need to be able to access each tile individually so created the following class to represent each tiles individual information.

```
class cTile
{
    //a class representing position in the graphics api im using (irrlicht)
    position2d<s32> Position;
    int imgIndex_x; 
    int imgIndex_y;
    int offset;
    // a class representing a square in the graphics api im using (irrlicht)
    rect<s32> TextureSq;
    // initialized at a negative number because zero is a valid number represent the global id number of tile ie its texture      
    int Gid = -1;                                                      

public:
    cTile();
    ~cTile();

    bool isSolid;
    void animate();
    void setGid(int gid);
    int getGid();
    void setSolid(bool state);
    void draw(IVideoDriver* vdr, ITexture * sourceImage);
};
```

When i try to delare an array of this class such as `cTile tiles[5]` i get:

`Error  1   error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes`

Comment: what's `sizeof(cTile)`?

Comment: @Robert yeah, my guess is that is can't be more than ~40, so something else is wrong.

Comment: @IdeaHat maybe something's wrong with `position2d` or `rect`... That's why I would like to know the size, just to get sure ^^

Comment: Generally the answer would be "allocate massive arrays dynamically", but `sizeof(cTile)` would have to be at least 410 MiB in order for that array to exceed`0x7fffffff` in size so I agree with the others in that something is probably not right.

Comment: @Dcoollx You aren't declaring the array of `cTile`s inside the `class cTile` are you?

Comment: Can you post the context in wich you are declaring/allocating the array?

Comment: @JonathanMee: That is not possible.

Comment: Maybe your array is bigger than the stack. Use a vector

Comment: @JonathanMee No I was declaring inside of a `int main()` that i created to test the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilers and operating systems usually set the size of local variable memory space smaller than the space for dynamic memory.

One easy solution is to use `std::vector`.

The other solution is to allocate your array "on the heap" by using `operator new`.

Comment: thanks, using a vector works, just to let you know though the original context did use the `new` key word as `tiles = new ctiles[max]` and got the sam error. but using a vector worked fine.